# Magento2 Dynamic System->Configuration Comments

Tags: magento2, configuration, magento-2.0

In Magento 1.x you could have dynamic comments on `system->configuration` fields by declaring your field in `system.xml` like this:

```
<field_code_here translate="label">
    <label>Label Here</label>
    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
    <comment>
        <model>[module]/field_comment</model><!-- this made it dynamic -->
    </comment>
</field_code_here>
```

Then you just need to create the `[Namespace]/[Module]/Model/Field/Comment.php` file with this content:

```
class [Namespace]_[Module]_Model_Field_Comment 
{
    public function getCommentText()  //the method has to be named getCommentText
    {
        //do some calculations here
        return 'Some string based on the calculations';
    }
}
```

This way the field would have as comment what the  `getCommentText` method from above returned.
Is there an alternative for Magento 2? It seams that I cannot attach a model to a comment tag. The `system.xml` is not validated by `Magento/Backend/etc/system_file.xsd` if I do.

Comment: Can you cite a use case?

Comment: @benmarks For Magento 1, I got this from EE1.13. I hope I'm allowed to show it. It's from the system.xml for the `Enterprise_SalesArchive` module `<comment><model>enterprise_salesarchive/system_config_backend_active</model></comment>`.  because of this comment model I would see in the `system->configuration` the number of archived orders.  I've used this approach on numerous custom extensions and it worked on CE also. Obviously I cannot find a case in Magento 2. If I did I wouldn't be asking this question. I would just replicate that case.

Comment: @benmarks. IN case you are wondering why I need it, I'm planning to clone this magento 1 extension https://github.com/tzyganu/stock-filter to magento 2, for learning purposes. And in that extension I used this comment model approach to show a message under a config field, [depending on the value of an other config field](https://github.com/tzyganu/stock-filter/blob/master/app/code/community/Easylife/StockFilter/Model/Enabled/Comment.php#L19)

Comment: Hmm. I want to say that the comment field is static by design, and I wonder if this is a UX best practice. If there's variability based on another field, that should be part of the overall message. That said, I can understand your case. Might be worth a discussion or PR on our GitHub.

Comment: @benmarks. So what you are saying is that this feature was not ported to M2? If so, please add it as an answer. If not...well do nothing. :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is related to a pre release version of Magento 2, more info here: http://meta.magento.stackexchange.com/questions/907/magento-2-questions-tagged-beta-alpha-pre-alpha-etc-quo-vadis

Comment: Still relevant for 2.0 since the issue was closed after the release

Comment: I would say this is relevant. I edited the answer to fit the latest magento version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[EDIT]**
In the latest magento version this is possible in a similar way as in M2. I fixed it :)

**[Original Answer]**

It seams that this feature is partially implemented in Magento 2. It doesn't work yet.
In the code that generates the configuration form there is the method `Magento\Backend\Model\Config\Structure\Element\Field::getComment`:

```
public function getComment($currentValue = '')
{
    $comment = '';
    if (isset($this->_data['comment'])) {
        if (is_array($this->_data['comment'])) {
            if (isset($this->_data['comment']['model'])) {
                $model = $this->_commentFactory->create($this->_data['comment']['model']);
                $comment = $model->getCommentText($currentValue);
            }
        } else {
            $comment = parent::getComment();
        }
    }
    return $comment;
}
```

This method should handle the case when the comment is generated by a model, but the validation schema does not allow a `model` tag inside the comment tag because the comment is defined like this:

```
<xs:element name="comment" type="xs:string" />
```

[I already opened a ticked on github](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/770)

Comment: Please see this PR for the instructions: https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/2626

Comment: I've seen that PR... Because I MADE IT :).

Comment: haha, I know :) just for the reference.